# How to terminate a dynamic executed code using CSharpCodeProvider?

Tags: c#, dynamic, timeout, execute, csharpcodeprovider

I am developing a website which let user type in their code and run to show output (just like Linqpad). I used `CSharpCodeProvider` but I also want to set timeout for the code, so that it will not break system if their code is too slow or have infinite loop. Because the code is dynamic from user, how can I achieve that? I tried `CancellationToken` but look like it need to be called from inside the dynamic source code, not outside.

Comment: do you mean cancel running or compiling?

Comment: @LeiYang mean cancel the running dynamic compiled code

Comment: what about `Process.Kill`

Comment: @LeiYang how and where exactly you put Process.Kill

Comment: then how did you start/run it?

Comment: I am running methodInfo.Invoke(myobject, invokeInput)

Comment: It is crucial that you sandbox the code so they can't p0wn your server.  That requires an AppDomain, unloading it also automagically aborts a thread that is running in the AD.  Focus on making the safe, the rest comes along for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I forgot to check `IsCancellationRequested`, below is the working code:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)state;
    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var invokeInput = new object[] { input };
        var output = mi.Invoke(o, invokeInput);
    }
}, cts.Token, cts.Token);


if (!newTask.Wait(timeout, cts.Token))
{
    cts.Cancel();
    throw new Exception("The operation has timed out.");
}
```